# Getting datetimes from cron format using javascript

Tags: javascript, cron

Does anyone know of any existing solutions using javascript that can parse a crontab and return all datetime instances between a given start and end date?

ie if i have `0 * * * *`, start `24/10/2011 16:00` and end `24/10/2011 19:00` then it will return:

```
24/10/2011 16:00,
24/10/2011 17:00,
24/10/2011 18:00
```

Comment: Crontag? Tpyo[sic]? You want to parse the "* */4 * * * *"-type crontab entries and turn that into real dates/times?

Comment: Adding to @MarcB, ...or a range of dates/times?

Comment: The way I get it, the input is: startdate, enddate and a crontab line. The output shall be the exact datetimes when the crontab command will run between the two given dates.

Comment: Yeah exactly, ie if i have `0 * * * *`, start `24/10/2011 16:00` and end `24/10/2011 19:00` then it will return `24/10/2011 16:00, 24/10/2011 17:00, 24/10/2011 18:00`

Comment: Updated the question based on the OP's comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might want to check out [Later.js](https://github.com/bunkat/later) which can parse a Cron expression and calculate the next occurrences.

```
var schedule = cronParser().parse('* */5 * * * *', true);
var results = later(60).get(schedule, 100, startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: ended up coding this myself, so a bit late for me, but looks good! thanks

Comment: That's great, why don't you share this as a package?

Comment: `var schedule = later.parse.cron('* */5 * * * *', true);
var results = later.schedule(schedule).next(100, new Date('2016-01-25'), new Date('2016-02-25') )`

Comment: Is this compatible with Java quartz cron scheduler? My use case is to use a compatible scheduler so the cron-expression can be used by backend or Front-End to get a occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much help, but it's a start. There are some java (not javascript) and php solutions that have some decent code that you'd want to translate and incorporate if you end up writing this yourself.

Take a look at these two bits of code:

http://www.redmoon.ch/?p=39

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2568-PHP-Parse-cron-tab-files-to-retrieve-job-schedules.html

HTH

Answer (score 1):

One can use ***cron-parser*** lib.
More info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser)